# Calculate this limit

Tags: limits, logarithms

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}  \dfrac{x - \ln(x+1)}{x \ln(x+1)}$$

I need help with this one .I couldn't figure out anything that could solve it .

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 8):

Note that 
$$\dfrac{x-\ln{(x+1)}}{x\ln{(x+1)}}=\dfrac{x}{x\ln{(x+1)}}-\dfrac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x\ln{(x+1)}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x \pm \ln (x + 1) \sim x$  (the logarithm is negligible)
Then

$$\frac{x - \ln(x+1)}{x \ln(x+1)} \sim \frac{x}{x \ln(x+1)} = \frac{1}{\ln(x+1)}$$

So

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x - \ln(x+1)}{x \ln(x+1)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(x+1)} = 0$$